# Pregunta de entrevista Balanceado parentesis

Tags: javascript, java, c#, c, consola

Buenos dias realice una entrevista el otro dia y el ejercicio consistia en contar y ver si los parentesis estaban balanceados y retornar como resultado la cantidad que faltaban balancear ej:

(()) 0    ((()) 1

Yo realice mi codigo y de los 16 test a correr solo 2 no corrieron:

```java
String s = "()))))))))))))))))))))))()()))()))))))))()))))))()))()))))(()))))))))))))()))))))(()))))))))()()))))))))))))()))))(())()))))))(()))))()))))))()))()())))())))))))))))()))())(()()())()()())))))()))))())()))()))))))))))))))()())))()))))()))))))()))())()))())))(()))()))))))))())))())))(())()))))()((()))))))((((()())())())(())))))())())))))))())))))()(()))))()))))())))))()())())()))()))))))))()))))))))))()))))())))))(((()))))()))((())))())))))))())))()()())())))))())))())())))))(())())))))))())))()()))))))))))))(())())())))((()))))))(())))()())))()))))(())))(())))))))))))))(())))(())()))))(()))())())))))))()())(()(())())))))))))))))))))))))))((()())))())))())))((()())))()))())()))))())()())))))))))))(()))))))))))))))()))))))()))))))))))))))))(()(()))(()))()))))))()))()()))))))))))()))())()))))())))()()()))()))))(())))))))))))))()()))))(())))()))))))()))()())()))())()())())))()()(()())))))()())))))))())))())))(())))())))))))()))))))))()((()(())))))))))(())))())))())))))))))()())))()))))))))(";
```

Este es el string en cuestion dandome como resultado 562 y en el test tendria q haber dado 564  mi pregunta es en que estoy fallando que esta mal?? O mi codigo esta bien y el test estaba mal.
dejo mi codigo aca:

```
 public static int metodo1(String s) {
        int parentesisIzq = 0;
        int parentesisDerecha = 0;
        int resultado = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '(') {
                parentesisIzq++;
            } else if (s.charAt(i) == ')') {
                parentesisDerecha++;
            }
        }
        resultado = parentesisDerecha - parentesisIzq;
        resultado = Math.abs(resultado);
        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. Pon en el título _cuál es el problema_. 2. No agregues cualquier etiqueta: solo pon la que corresponde a tu pregunta.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488391/como-convertir-una-expresi%c3%b3n-de-notaci%c3%b3n-infija-a-notaci%c3%b3n-postfijao-polaca-inv no es exactamente lo que buscas pero puede servirte para un futuro

Comment: Para poder ayudarte debes de agregar las reglas para considerar si un paréntesis es balanceado que es donde puede estar tu error, de lo contrario no hay una base sobre la que evaluar tu lógica.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no entendiste correctamente el problema, te dicen "que paréntesis no está pareados", pero tu solo estás contando cuantos hay de abrir y cuantos hay de cerrar eso significa que en este código: `)(` donde los paréntesis no están pareados, tu devuelves 0 cuando debería devolver 2.

El código correcto sería:

```java
public static int metodo1(String s) {
    int parentesisIzqSinParear = 0;
    int parentesisDerSinParear = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '(') {
            // parentesis izquierda sin parear
            parentesisIzqSinParear++;
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == ')' && parentesisIzqSinParear>0) {
            // solo si hay paréntesis a la izquierda sin cerrar, los cerramos
            parentesisIzqSinParear--;
        } else {
            // si no hay parentesis sin cerrar, entonces es un paréntesis derecha huerfano.
            parentesisDerSinParear++;
        }
    }
    return parentesisIzqSinParear + parentesisDerSinParear;
}
```

Comment: Bien ahí ing. magíster Al-Lee :D