# Cómo convertir un valor string a int en c# ( Cómo pasar una operación con parentesis de tipo string a int para poder resolverla)

Tags: c#

Necesito de su ayuda por favor.
Estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación y mi problema actual es este, estoy trabajando en una calculadora en c#, necesito pasar un valor de tipo string a int para poder resolver la operación que contiene la variable. He intentado con Convert pero la operación contiene paréntesis y a la hora de querer convertirlo a tipo numérico no me deja por los paréntesis,

Ejemplo:

```
string operacion = "(2+2)*2";
```

la cadena anterior  la quiero pasar a int para poder resolver la operación, pero no me deja por los parentesis,

```
string aParentesis = "(";
string cParentesis = ")";
int numero1 = 2;
int numero2 = 2;
int numero3 = 4;
string concatenar = "+";
string mult = "*";
var resultado = aParentesis+numero1+concatenar+numero2+cParentesis+mult+num3;
```

Alguna solución u otra forma mas factible de resolver esto?
alguna idea de como trabajar de una mejor forma con los paréntesis,
al final lo que necesito es poder resolver la operación de acuerdo a los valores que se obtenga de un entry.

Comment: Aunque no es ULTRA complejo, creo que es más complicado de lo que estimas. Asumiendo que entiendo lo que escribiste, recibirás la operación en un string, y luego la procesarás de acuerdo a los símbolos dentro de la cadena? De ser así, necesitarás investigar acerca de 'pilas'. Deberás leer cada caracter y decidir si meterlo a la pila, y luego deberás realizar operaciones con los elementos dentro de la pila.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10457244/13419694

Comment: @Mateo, al igual que con las respuestas, considera añadir *al menos* una explicación breve de por qué consideras que el link resuelve el problema de OP. Yo opino que no lo hace, porque *al parecer* OP busca un [lexical analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) .

Comment: Con las funciones que brinda el namespace System de .NET las posibilidades que tienes son generar código y compilarlo en tiempo de ejecución. Si la solución no te convence, puede que te interese un evaluador de expresiones de tercero o escribir uno propio, lo que implica más que un simple analizador léxico.

Comment: entra aqui todo esta resuelto y explicado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488391/como-convertir-una-expresi%c3%b3n-de-notaci%c3%b3n-infija-a-notaci%c3%b3n-postfijao-polaca-inv

Comment: gracias por su ayuda