# Calculadora en c#

Tags: c#

actualmente estoy haciendo una calculadora en c#, con windows forms, basicamente realiza operaciones basicas, +,-,* y / y tambien tiene en cuenta parentesis (), estoy teniendo un problema ya que quiero que al ingresar un parentesis luego de un numero se multiplique automaticamente, por ejemplo 8(9+2), actualmente si coloco eso, me sale syntax error ya que no hay ningun operador antes del parentesis, Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

```
private void btnIgual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //= button
        {
            double resultado;
            if (EvaluarExpresion(_expresion, out resultado))
            {
                if (double.IsInfinity(resultado))
                {
                    txtResultado.Text = "No se puede dividir por 0";
                    timerError.Start();
                }
                else if (double.IsNaN(resultado))
                {
                    txtResultado.Text = "Resultado no válido";
                    timerError.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtResultado.Text = resultado.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    _expresion = txtResultado.Text;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                txtResultado.Text = "Syntax Error";
                timerError.Start();
            }
        }
```

```
private bool EvaluarExpresion(string expresion, out double resultado)
        {
            resultado = 0;
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                resultado = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Compute(expresion, ""));
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: El sitio web es en idioma español, traduce tu pregunta de lo contrario será eliminada. saludos

Comment: entra aki https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488391/como-convertir-una-expresi%c3%b3n-de-notaci%c3%b3n-infija-a-notaci%c3%b3n-postfijao-polaca-inv

Answer (score 1):

Desarrollar una calculadora donde ingresas como texto la operación no es tan trivial, se requiere desglosar la operación en sub-operaciones en un árbol de expresiones.

Tu estas aprovechando la función `compute` del `DataTable` que lo hace por ti, pero estas expresiones deben seguir reglas, no existe la multiplicación implícita, tal como en mismo C# tampoco existe.

```
int resultado = 2(3+3); //Error
```

Entonces me parece que la única solución posible es agregar ese `*` que falta, donde puedes usar un `replace`, para esto deberás buscar los posibles problemas, por ejemplo:

- Los número seguido de paréntesis: `0(`,`1(`,`2(`...`9(`
- 2 paréntesis juntos, de cierre y apertura en ese orden: `)(`

Entonces creas una función:

```
 private string AgregarMulti(string expresion) {
     return expresion
         .Replace(" ", "") //opcional: quitamos los espacios
         .Replace("0(", "0*(")
         .Replace("1(", "1*(")
         .Replace("2(", "2*(")
         .Replace("3(", "3*(")
         .Replace("4(", "4*(")
         .Replace("5(", "5*(")
         .Replace("6(", "6*(")
         .Replace("7(", "7*(")
         .Replace("8(", "8*(")
         .Replace("9(", "9*(")
         .Replace(")(", ")*(");
 }
```

Y luego la llamas

```
dt.Compute(AgregarMulti(expresion),"")
```

*Otra forma sería usar expresiones regulares para buscar los casos.*