¿Como puedo indentificar una variable "x" en una cadena tipo string, para asi ser remplazada por valores tipo int, ejp "y=3+x" que se reconozca la x
Es en Microsoft visual c#
En teoría busco que se reconozca la "x" en el texto que coloque el usuario y lo pueda remplazar por valores ya definidos y así se pueda obtener un valor de la función que coloca el usuario


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

la x siempre es x.. o sea.. vos queres poder reemplazar esa x por que= (se hace con replace).. y luego? calcular el valor?? pues.. c# no funciona asi...

en C# no tengo mucho conocimiento,  el mejor lenguaje para realizar cálculos aritmético y matemático es el lenguaje MATLAB  que permite desarrollar algoritmos y cálculos con variable

Necesitas crear un evaluador de expresiones. Es complicado, pero hay alternativas. Usar una librería como C# Eval Expression o compilar código.

eh, lo que trato de hacer es que, un usuario externo escriba una función en el textbox, ejp (3x-1), esta seria tipo string, entonces quisiera que el programa encuentre la x y la remplace con una tabla de valores por ejp, f(1)=3(1)-1 = 2,y seguir remplazando con el 2,3,4,5...10,  es posible?
posdata: es c# en Microsoft visual estudio code, lo aclaro porque la respuesta de abajo no me funciono.

en conclusion quiero hacer un geogebra pero en c# pero con solo funciones lineales, es posible?

@klimergiron revisa está respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488391/como-convertir-una-expresi%c3%b3n-de-notaci%c3%b3n-infija-a-notaci%c3%b3n-postfijao-polaca-inv

@klimergiron Que es lo que no te funcionó de la respuesta de abajo????

Digamos que tú tienes la función matemática f(x) = 3 + x, en C# sería
// A este tipo de funciones se les llama "Lambda"
var f = (decimal x) => 3 + x;  // o Func<decimal,decimal> f = x => 3 + x;

f(10); // es 13
f(11); // es 14
f(12); // es 15
//etc

Como vez se reemplaza la x al igual que una función matemática, por lo que tu problema de fondo es crear una "función C#" a partir de un string
C# cuenta con una poderosa herramienta llamada Expression que permite crear (o analizar) un árbol de expresiones. Junto con esto, existe ádemas, DynamicExpressionParser de la biblioteca:
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

La cual, justamente tiene métodos que permiten transformar un string en una Expression. Y toda Expression al compilarla retorna una función (un delegado para ser preciso)
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1;
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] valorPredefinidos = [1, 2, 3, 4];

        string expression = "3+x";
        var f = CreateFuncion(expression);

        foreach(var v in valorPredefinidos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f(v));
        }
        //imprime:
        // 4
        // 5
        // 6
        // 7
    }
    static Func<decimal, decimal> CreateFuncion(string expression)
    {
        // Crea el parámetro de la expresión
        ParameterExpression parametro = Expression.Parameter(typeof(decimal), "x");
        
        //transformamos el string en una Expression
        var exp = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda([parametro], typeof(decimal), expression);
        return (Func<decimal, decimal>)exp.Compile();
    }
 }


Tremenda respuesta, mis respetos!!!

Gracias, muchas gracias

@Japv Muchas gracias por tu comentario!!!!
